# How to make Jersey / Moxy more restrictive when unmarshaling JSON?

Tags: jax-rs, moxy, jersey-2.0

I'm currently using Jersey and Moxy in Glassfish 4. Is there a way to tell Jersey/Moxy to refuse a HTTP request if its JSON content is not valid (i.e. it contains more objects than it should when binding JSON to a POJO) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create my own subclass of `MOXyJsonProvider` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html).  Then in that subclass I would override the `preReadFrom` method.  In that method I would set an `Unmarshaller.Listener`.

```
@Override
protected void preReadFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller) throws JAXBException {
    Unmarshaller.Listener ul = new YourUnmarshallerListener();
    unmarshaller.setListener(ul);
}
```

Then `Unmarshaller.Listener` would then count each time an object was unmarshalled and error out if too many are read.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you! I suppose this code is automatically injected on Glassfish thanks to the `@Provider` annotation, right?